# Linux - Create ftp account with read/write access to only 1 folder

Tags: linux, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux - Create ftp account with read/write access to only 1 folder](https://serverfault.com/questions/137613/linux-create-ftp-account-with-read-write-access-to-only-1-folder)

Hey guys....

I have never worked on linux and dont plan on working on it either - The only command I probably know is "ls" :)

I am hosting my website on Eapps and use their cpanel to setup everything so never worked with linux.

Now I have this one time case - where I need to provide access to a contractor to fix the CSS issues on my website. He basically needs FTP (read/write) access to certain folders.

At a high level - this is my code structure

```
/home/webadmin/example.com/html/images
                               /css
                               /js
                               /login.php
                               /facebook.php

/home/webadmin/example.com/application/library
                                      /views
                                      /models
                                      /controllers
                                      /config
                                      /bootstrap.php

/home/webadmin/example.com/cgi-bin
```

I want the new user to be able to have access to only these folders

```
/home/webadmin/example.com/html/js
/home/webadmin/example.com/html/css
/home/webadmin/example.com/application/views
```

He should not be able to view even the content of other folders including files like bootstrap.php or login.php etc

If any sys admins can help me set this account up - will really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is possible and how to do it depends on the software that running there and the permissions you have. Most likely the best way is to ask the tech support to do it for you.

Comment: Well I have root access